# Excel macro to order varying number of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 10 columns (column A, column B, ... , column J). I'm trying to create a macro to order those columns (i.e. to end up with something like column B, column D, column A, ... , column E) according to the entries in rows 1 and 3 (first sorting by values A to Z in row 1, then by values A to Z in row 3).

This is easy if I record myself doing it. However, if in the future the number of columns that need to be ordered changes (e.g. if two new columns are added), the macro recorded in this way no longer works. How can I create a macro that will perform this ordering on highlighted columns?

Thanks

Comment: You should post examples of what you have tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything since I have no idea how to go about it

Comment: Can you post what you get when you record the steps?  Should be relatively straightforward to modify that to deal with a different starting range.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the comments posted before, here is a bit of encouragement for your growth.
Code For deletion of known header names

```
'   Delete Extranious Rows based on header name
    Dim cellcolumn As Integer
'   Replace each name in "" with the names of headers you do want
    For Each b In Array("Unit Type", "Unit Profile", "Drop Profile", "Delivery Type", "Activity Time", "Miles")
        On Error Resume Next
        rng1 = b
        strSearch = rng1
            Set aCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                                        SearchFormat:=False)
            cellcolumn = aCell.Column
            Columns(cellcolumn).EntireColumn.Select
            Selection.Intert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next b
```

The task you are trying to complete can be accomplished in more ways than one.  This method will delete extranious information.  The next segment organizes information when you know what you want moved and where.

```
Sub Organize()

'   Organize Trip Stat
    Dim Heder(1 To 5) As String
    Heder(1) = "trip_id"
    Heder(2) = "driver_id"
    Heder(3) = "route_nbr"
    Heder(4) = "trailer_id"
    Heder(5) = "trip_type_code"
    For a = 1 To 5

Call Organize(Heder(a))

Next a
End Sub
```

The next code is called upon to complete the process

```
Function Organize(TheHeder)
For b = 1 To 50
If Cells(1, b).Text = TheHeder Then
Cells(1, b).EntireColumn.Select
    If Range("B1").Text = TheHeder Then GoTo nextstep:
    Selection.Cut
    Columns(2).Select
    Selection.Insert (xlToRight)
End If
Next b
nextstep:
End Function
```

These two steps have been useful to me in my endeavors.  Keep searching and learning!

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SortColumns()

    Dim rngSort As Range

    With ActiveSheet

        Set rngSort = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion

        With .Sort.SortFields
        .Clear

        .Add Key:=rngSort.Rows(1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                             Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .Add Key:=rngSort.Rows(3), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                             Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With

        With .Sort
            .SetRange rngSort
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, I like your code its a bit cleaner.  I just try to avoid the column references, and prefer the variable approach. Good Share Sir.